# How can I Cancel the transferred iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I have transferred the app from one account to another account. all process is done and app status in my new account is Active but not showing the app in new account and not removed in old account?

Comment: Not showing on Xcode or not showing on website? Is your question about "showing" something, or about cancelling a transfer ?

Comment: about app cancel

Comment: Transferred the app not showing in new Apple account on website.

Comment: Then, looking at the [tag:app-store-connect] tag description, "_Do not post questions related to needing support and issues with the website._", I'm not sure if it's on topic for Stack Overflow.